# Filter data.table based on string match from another vector

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to select rows in a data.table. I need the values in variable `dt$s` to start with any of the strings in vector `y`

```
dt <- data.table(x = (c(1:5)), s = c("a", "ab", "b.c", "db", "d"))
y <- c("a", "b")
```

Desired result:

```
   x   s
1: 1   a
2: 2  ab
3: 3 b.c
```

I would use `dt[s %in% y]` for a full match, and `%like%` or `"^a*"` for a partial match with a single string, but I'm not sure how to get a strict `starts with` match on a character vector.

My real dataset and character vector is quite large, so I'd appreciate an efficient solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You received excellent answers. Despite much effort, I have never had any luck with base:: startsWith() as a filter ('i') in a data.table chain. startsWith() seems as if it should work. But it just doesn't: Try   dt[startsWith(y,s),] to see it fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pattern dynamically from `y`.

```
library(data.table)
pat <- sprintf('^(%s)', paste0(y, collapse = '|'))
pat
#[1] "^(a|b)"
```

and use it to subset the data.

```
dt[grepl(pat, s)]

#   x   s
#1: 1   a
#2: 2  ab
#3: 3 b.c
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Using `glue` and `filter`

```
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dt %>% 
  filter(str_detect(s, glue("^({str_c(y, collapse = '|')})")))
#   x   s
#1: 1   a
#2: 2  ab
#3: 3 b.c
```